# How to install pandas through SSH on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, pandas

I am attempting to run some Python code on the default Amazon EC2 instance. I ran the following command to get the version:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-0-107 ~]$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.4.62-53.42.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31004) (gcc versio n 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Sep 20 07:23:24 UTC 2013
```

Now I want to install pandas. So I did:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-0-107 ~]$ sudo yum install pandas

Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
```

No package pandas available.

How do I install pandas on Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think pandas is in the Redhat packages as python-pandas, in which case:
`sudo yum install python-pandas`
Unfortunately, Redhat does not publicly publish a list of their packages so I'm not sure.

Alternatively you can use the python packaging system, pip. To install pip:

`sudo easy_install pip`

and then

`sudo pip install pandas`

Answer (score 5):

The solution suggested by foobarbecue did not work for me. Instead, follow the commands below, ENTIRELY copied from [this post](https://blog.datapolitan.com/2015/08/25/installing-matplotlib-and-pandas-on-amazon-ec2/), and it should solve your problem. Also, make sure you read the comments as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum install update
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install python-devel libpng-devel freetype-devel 
#the last two are necessary for pip to run without failing with 
#error 'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1'
sudo pip install pandas #Finally it works!
```

Comment: Just a quick note, if somebody wants to install it on Python 3, change `python-devel` to `python3-devel` and `pip` to `pip3`

Answer (score 3):

I'm just recently setup EC2 RHCL and also look for PIP installation, so I would like to share my latest update

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

Installating collected packages: numpy, pandas

Now we have both NumPy and pandas installed

Comment: it installed tje package but library is not there.

Answer (score 0):

**sudo pip3 install pandas**
this command has worked on aws EC2 terminal

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57630556/18145256).